# show that $f(y_n)<0=f(0)< f(x_n) $ for all n?

Tags: calculus

show that $f(y_n)<0=f(0)< f(x_n) $ for all n

where  f(x)= $ \{ x^4 \sin (\frac{1}{x}) , x\neq0\\
                   \;\;\;\;0 , \;\;\;x=0  \;\;\;\}$

$x_n= \frac{2}{(4n+1)\pi}, y_n= \frac{2}{(4n+3)\pi}$

here clearly f(0)=0, but we prove that this inqallity

Comment: sorry i edited now

Answer (score 0):

Since we have

$$\sin (x+2k\pi)=\sin x\;,\;\;\text{forall}\;\;k\in \Bbb Z\;,\;\;\;\text{ we get that:}$$

$$f(x_n)=\frac{2^4}{(4n+1)^4\pi^4}\sin\left(\frac{4n+1}2\pi\right)=\frac{16}{(4n+1)^4\pi^4}\sin\left(\frac\pi2+2n\pi\right)=\frac{16}{(4n+1)^4\pi^4}>0$$

since $\;\sin\frac\pi2=1\;$

Now you try to do the rest.